Is my assumption true? A quadrilateral with two sides parallel and two other congruent is either trapezoid or parallelogram
Consider the following drawing having three circles and two parallel lines:

I can connect the lines mainly in two different ways (excluding the 'triangle' way):

or this:

So with this construction, I can either get a triangle (not shown on the drawings above), a trapezoid, or a parallelogram. I have two questions related to this:

Is it possible to conclude from that the theorem that a quadrilateral with two sides parallel and two other sides congruent is either a trapezoid or a parallelogram?
If so, then, if I'm given a quadrilateral with two sides parallel and two other sides congruent, how do I formally differentiate the 'trapezoid' and 'parallelogram' cases?


A parallelogram has each pair of opposite sides having equal lengths which are parallel (and each pair of opposite angles being equal); a non-parallelogram has none of these properties.

I was thinking about a proof involving half-planes or something like that to distinguish two cases.

What's your definition of a "trapezoid"?  I thought a trapezoid was a quadrilateral with one pair of parallel sides.  Thus, yes, you quadrilateral must be either a parallelogram or a trapezoid as those are the only two options.... But if you mean that the two sides must be either parallel, or creating equal interior angles, that is correct.  (To prove this extend the sides until they and consider the resulting pair of similar triangles. They are either both isoceles or both not.)

So it's either a parallelogram, or a trapezoid, or .... what? what is the third option?  (from wikipedia:  In geometry, a trapezoid in North American English, or trapezium (/trəˈpiːziəm/) in British English,is a quadrilateral that has one pair of parallel sides.
The parallel sides are called the bases of the trapezoid. The other two sides are called the legs (or the lateral sides) if they are not parallel; otherwise, the trapezoid is a parallelogram, and there are two pairs of bases. )
So it's  parallelgram (two pairs of parallel sides), trapezoid (one pair), or no pairs.

The definitions are that if a quadrilateral has no pair of sides that are parallel there is not special term for it.
If quadrilateral has one pair of parallel sides but the other pair are not parallel it is, by definition, a trapezoid.
If the quadrilateral has two pairs of parallel sides but the other pair or not then it is, by definition, a parallelogram.
So, by definition, a quadrilateral with at least one pair of parallel sides, is, by exhaustion, either a parallelogram or a trapezoid.  Those are, by definition, the only two options.


is true, on the North American version of trapezoid (2 and only 2 sides parallel in quadrangle); 2) just knowing congruence is not sufficient, you will need other information to determine which case (trapezoid vs parallelogram) fits


If you're from the school of thought that says a square is a special kind of rectangle, as I am, then a parallelogram is a special kind of trapezoid and the other shape you get is another special kind of trapezoid, namely an isosceles trapezoid.
Under inclusive definitions of shapes (which seems to be the preferred way in mathematics in this century, although many dictionaries still give definitions from a couple of centuries ago), a trapezoid is any simple quadrilateral with two parallel sides. It is then redundant to say "a trapezoid or a parallelogram"; if you know that an object is a trapezoid or a parallelogram, you know it is a trapezoid.
An example of a quadrilateral that is not simple is the quadrilateral connecting the vertices $(0,0)$, $(1, 0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,1)$, and back to $(0,0)$ in that sequence.


Is it possible to conclude from that the theorem that a quadrilateral with two sides parallel and two other sides congruent is either a trapezoid or a parallelogram?


This is only true if "quadrilateral" is assumed to mean a simple quadrilateral. Otherwise the non-simple quadrilateral I described earlier is a counterexample.
But assuming every "quadrilateral" is simple, then the theorem is true because any quadrilateral with two sides parallel is a trapezoid.
You can also make the theorem more specific:

A simple quadrilateral with two sides parallel and two other sides congruent is either an isosceles trapezoid or a parallelogram.

I think that may be the theorem you want, although the two cases (isosceles trapezoid or a parallelogram) are not exclusive in that context; a rectangle has two sides parallel and two other sides congruent and is both an isosceles trapezoid and a parallelogram. I suspect you don't want rectangles, since you didn't draw one; perhaps you should be a little more explicit about the exact constraints you observe in constructing your quadrilaterals. (For example, are the angles always either $45$ or $135$ degrees, as they are in both your figures?)


If so, then, if I'm given a quadrilateral with two sides parallel and two other sides congruent, how do I formally differentiate the 'trapezoid' and 'parallelogram' cases?


To distinguish the case of a parallelogram from the case of an isosceles trapezoid, you could investigate whether the "two other sides congruent" are also parallel.
Alternatively, you could investigate whether the original "two sides parallel" are also congruent. If they are, you have a parallelogram.
How you do this depends entirely on what additional information you have about the trapezoid. In your figure we have a set of congruent circles with centers spaced at equal intervals along a line and named tangent points spaced at equal intervals along another line; you could count the number of such points along each edge of the quadrilateral, or compare the relative positions of the circles whose center and tangent point you used for the endpoints of each "congruent" side.
